# Replace empty strings with NULL instead of empty strings when using JOIN

Tags: postgresql, types

I have two tables:

table_a

```
id      name
1       john
2       dave
3       tim
4       marta
5       jim
```

table_b

```
id      sum         random_metric
1       10.50       abc
3       11.5        efg
5       5.76        ghj
```

I have joined them on `id`

```
SELECT ...
FROM table_a 
  LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
```

and I get:

```
id      name        sum         random_metric
1       john        10.5        abc
2       dave
3       tim         11.5        efg
4       marta
5       jim         5.76        ghj
```

Then I want to convert the `sum` column to double precision but since it has empty strings in rows 2, 4 it does not work.

How could I join tables so that I would have this:

```
id      name        sum         random_metric
1       john        10.5        abc
2       dave        NULL        NULL
3       tim         11.5        efg
4       marta       NULL        NULL
5       jim         5.76        ghj
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of fixing the data not to have empty strings in the first place, i.e. convert them to NULL?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete statement you are using. "Missing data for ..." does not sound like a Postgres error message

Comment: You don't get empty strings. They are NULLs.

Comment: I do, because when I try to use CAST(sum as double precision) I get error when it tries to cast it to row 2 value of sum which is (probably) an empty strings because in DB I do not see NULL value like in other columns when I state case .. else NULL.

Comment: `nullif(trim(sum), '')`?

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=91c4df998f627815f3e805d79797a07c

Comment: The result of unmatched rows in a LEFT join are NULLs and not empty strings.

Comment: I see @forpas, I will check what might cause the join to have empty strings and not NULL values. Thank you.